# Create a class/method for a time (start, reset, stop, get istant, get timerun)

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, methods, time

I'm building a racing game and I'm working on race times.

I try to build a system to start an instance of a timer with various options.

My little experience is putting me in crisis ... would some good soul want to help me?

This was the idea:

```
public class Timer {


    public float counter;
    public bool reset; 
    public string runtime = "--:--:--";
    public string istant = "not istant";

    public void startTimer()
    {

        /* inupdatealternative: counter += Time.deltaTime; */

        if(reset == true)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            counter = Time.time;
        }

        var minutes = counter/60;               // divide guitime by sixty (minutes)
        var seconds = counter%60;               // euclidean division (seconds)
        var fraction = (counter * 100) % 100;   // get fraction of seconds
        runtime = string.Format ( "{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:000}", minutes, seconds, fraction);

        Debug.Log("in Start: "+runtime);

    }

    public void resetTimer()
    {
        reset = true;
    }

    public string getTimerRuntime()
    {
        return runtime;
    }

    public string getTimerIstant()
    {
        istant = runtime;
        return istant;
    }

}
```

in update, for exemple:

```
var lapTimer = new Timer(); // create a new timer
if(Lap < Pilot.pilotlap )
{
    lapTimer.startTimer();
    Lap++
}
else if(Lap==Pilot.pilotlap)
{
    timerLabel.text = lapTimer.getTimerIstant();
    lapTimer.resetTimer();
    lapTimer.startTimer();
}
```

in my head I'm sure someone has already dealt with it ... surely there will be something that manages the times and returns values ​​in various ways: does it exist? or is there anyway how to make or build such a thing?

Comment: Have you looked at `TimeSpan`?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is something not working as expected?

Comment: I didn't know timespan ... now I study it. Thanks.

Yes, the variables not change when I call the actions. Probably, I coming from javascript and I have difficulty with methods and classes of c#.

Time starts ... but does not reset and does not return values:

Comment: and also time part but is not returned

Comment: therefore, the question might as well be: How the hell do I create return started time, the piece of started time, and now reset everything and restart?

I realize that it is not a "two minute" help

Comment: Have you looked at the Stopwatch-class (System.Diagnostics)

Answer (score 1):

There is, it's called `Stopwatch`, it's THE class used in C# to use precise timers, and it's located in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Using your `Update()` example, you can use it like this:

```cs
// Create a new stopwatch instance
// If the timer is used repeatedly, just instantiate one at start and re-use the same,
// to avoid garbage generation
Stopwatch lapTimer = new Stopwatch();

if(Lap < Pilot.pilotlap )
{
    lapTimer.Start();
    Lap++
}
else if(Lap==Pilot.pilotlap)
{
    lapTimer.Stop();
    // ElapsedMilliseconds returns exactly what it says, so you may need to format the value
    // before passing it to the timerLabel.text
    timerLabel.text = lapTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
    lapTimer.Reset();
    lapTimer.Start();
}
```

You can read about the class (its methods, fields and properties) here:

[Stopwatch Class Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: did you just "steel" Nils Lande's answer? ;)

Comment: In this case stopwatch works wonderfully, thank you.

It is not the kind of solution I was looking for but for now it is fine.

I'll come back to creating a specific class later, thanks to everyone.

Comment: I don't "steel", I "enheence". :D I just wanted to give a proper example of a simple use of the Stopwatch class, though, since it felt that OP didn't know at all of its existence.
@Alberto, what exactly do you want to accomplish then? When you get a specific elapsed amount of time, it's up to you to process it based on your needs, if you elaborate further on what you want, we can discuss further about it.

Comment: @Galandil I will surely deepen the question because, however, I don't want to rely on the library with a chronometer but to understand how to do it and refine.

Just enough time to solve this new discovery problem and come back here.

Comment: (to explain: I'm fighting with the Ui, raycasting and clicks and lerp rotation that block XD a mess) 

I solve and go back :D

Comment: @Alberto, I saw that you're italian, as I am, if you want to ask more questions you can contact me via the SE chat. ;)

Comment: @Galandil "daje! Si fa pure prima. ma per SE chat che intendi?"
Nice. It's done well before. what is SE chat?

Comment: @Alberto La chat di Stack Exchange, quella di qui insomma. ;)

Comment: @Alberto Ho creato una room, puoi joinarla usando questo link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/95177/only-italian-language?tab=general

Comment: @Galandil ci sto dentro... vedo che non ci sei e non capisco dove scrivere.
Fai un fischio quando vuoi domani che comunque faremo due chiacchiere ;)

Comment: stopwatch is for more precise stuff, timespan / datetime is going to be more useful here

Comment: @zambari Yes, in fact it is heavy on the game. I will have to build something similar but in a lighter and more practical way

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of unnecessary `bool` and local fields copiing and setting there. I would simply use something like

```
public class Timer 
{
    private float _startTime;
    public bool IsRunning;

    // you don't need an extra reset method
    // simply pass it as a parameter
    public void Start(bool reset = false)
    {
        if(IsRunning && !reset)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Timer is already running! If you wanted to restart consider passing true as parameter.");
            return;
        }

        _startTime = Time.time;                                             

        Debug.Log("in Start: " + GetFormattedTime(_startTime));

        IsRunning = true;
    }

    // depending what stop should do
    // since this doesn't use any resources while running you could also simply
    // only stick to the Start method and pass in true .. does basically the same
    public void Stop()
    {
        IsRunning = false;
    }

    // I didn't see any difference between you two methods so I would simply use
    public string GetCurrentTime()
    {
        if(!IsRunning)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Trying to get a time from a Timer that isn't running!");
            return "--:--:---";
        }

        var timeDifference = Time.time - _startTime;

        return GetFormattedTime(timeDifference);
    }

    private static string GetFormattedTime(float time)
    {
                                                                  // e.g. time = 74.6753
        var minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(time / 60f);               // e.g. 1 (rounded down)
        var seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(time - 60f * minutes);      // e.g.  14 (rounded down)
        var fraction = Mathf.RoundToInt((time - seconds) * 1000f); // e.g. 676 (rounded down or up)

        // Use a string interpolation for better readability
        return $"{minutes:00}:{seconds:00}:{fraction:000}";
    }
}
```

then in your `Update` you don't want to use

```
var lapTimer = new Timer(); // create a new timer
```

all the time since it would create a new timer and you wouldn't get any tracked time ... you rather would use it only once like

```
private Timer timer;

// just in case you want to keep track of needed times per lap
public List<string> lapTimes = new List<string>();

private void Awake()
{
    timer = new Timer();
    lapTimes.Clear();
}

private void Update()
{
    ...

    if(Lap < Pilot.pilotlap)
    {
        timer.Start();
        Lap++
    }
    else if(Lap == Pilot.pilotlap)
    {
        var currentTime = timer.GetCurrentTime();
        timerLabel.text = currentTime;
        lapTimes.Add(currentTime);
        timer.Start(true)
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that I don't know if this is all you have in `Update` or how you use it but you probably also do **not** want to (re)start the timer and count up the `Lap` **every frame** your conditions are `true` ... there should be more checks involved to make sure this can only be called **once per lap** ...